# Mscorcfg.msc disappeared !

Tags: .net, cas

In the past I used to configure .NET code groups with the Mscorcfg.msc utility. I could launch it in Configuration Panel/Administration Tools/.NET configuration Tools (or something like that).

But now, it doesn't appear anymore, I have tried to search in the %WINDIR% directory, but Mscorcfg.msc has really disappeared.

Now, how can I configure code groups ? (without the command line if possible T-T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you need to download the new version of the .NET sdk for vs 2008 and .NET 3.5:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

full story about why it disappeared with a .msi making it reappears here : http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/01/23/516671.aspx